# Integrate TeamCity Reports to Confluence

Tags: automation, build-automation, report, teamcity, confluence

Is there a way (plugin) to integrate build-reports from teamcity to confluence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for but Etienne Studer has bloged about [Confluence TeamCity Integration](http://www.therichwebexperience.com/blog/etienne_studer/2007/08/confluence_teamcity_integration) (it's pretty old but it's hard to be accurate without any informations on the versions you're using):

> TeamCity provides a widget that
>   displays the status of a given build
>   configuration in an arbitrary web
>   page. With a little help by Kir from
>   JetBrains, I was able to integrate the
>   External Status Widget into
>   Confluence.
>
> First, add the following section at
>   the beginning of
>   `TeamCity/webapps/ROOT/status/externalStatus.jsp`:
>
> ```
> <style type="text/css">
>   @import
>   "${pageContext.request.requestURL}/../../css/status/externalStatus.css";
> </style>
> ```
>
> Then, integrate the External Status
>   Widget for the build configurations of
>   interest into Confluence:
>
> ```
> h1. TeamCity
> |{html-include:url=http://tc.xy.com/externalStatus.html?buildTypeId=bt77}|
> |{html-include:url=http://tc.xy.com/externalStatus.html?buildTypeId=bt88}|
> |{html-include:url=http://tc.xy.com/externalStatus.html?buildTypeId=bt99}|
> ```
>
> That's it. Another fine feature of
>   TeamCity.
>
> In Benares, i.e. TeamCity 3, a link
>   will be available that also includes
>   the CSS information as part of the
>   returned HTML fragment and hence there
>   will be no more need to import the CSS
>   style information separately.
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [jroller.com](http://www.jroller.com/ulc/resource/tc_confluence.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Try the ["Confluence TeamCity Integration Plugin"](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/1015949)

It provides 4 macroses:

- Activity
- Agents
- Project
- Build Configuration

Also, it's free