# How to Integrate Teamcity Reports to Confluence

Tags: teamcity, confluence

I found this thread about my problem.

[Integrate TeamCity Reports to Confluence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486369/integrate-teamcity-reports-to-confluence)

I followed exactly the instructions, but I always get the same error.

My Widget looks like that:

[image: Widget in Confluence]

And when im click on it, I get this error:
[image: TomCatError]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to check: first you'll need to check that the "external status widget" option is enabled for the build you're trying to show (this is in the General Settings section of the Build Configuration settings) and then verify you're using the proper URL (TeamCity 6.0 seems to use /externalStatus*.html*). You should be able to view the external status HTML page in a regular browser window so check that first, also there should be a little help icon beside the external status widget option in the build configuration settings, it provides a few more details on using the external status.